# Border doesn't adapt to list-style: none;

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on designing my site, and at the moment I'm trying to sketch down the pricing elements of my SaaS. I want to have a border around my divs, but my problem is that the border goes where the list style "is", even though I have written it to be none. Or at least I think that is the error. I have no clue how to fix this! What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div id='pricing_plan2' class="grid_4">
    <ul class="plan">
        <li class="plan_price2">
            <span id="recommend">WE RECOMMEND</span><BR />
            <span class="dollar">$</span>
            <span class="price">14.99</span>
            <span class="month">/month</span>
        </li>
        <li class="plan_title2">
            STANDARD ACCOUNT
        </li>
        <li class="features">1GB storage</li>
        <li class="features">5GB bandwith</li>
        <li class="features">2 domains</li>
        <li class="features">3 databases</li>
        <li class="features">1 FTP account</li>
        <li class="features">25 Email Accounts</li>
     <li class="buynow"><a href="#">Choose standard plan</a></li>
    </ul>
```

here is the CSS:

```
    body {
    background-color: #fff;
}
#recommend {
    color: #becdd6;
}

.plan_title {
    background: #ecf2f6;
    padding:20px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9dee1;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.plan_price {
    color: #479ccf;
    background: #ecf2f6;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.dollar {
    font-size: 25px;
}
.price {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.month {
    font-size: 15px;
}

.features {
    background:blue;
}
.features:nth-child(odd){
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F7;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}
.features:nth-child(even){
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}
.buynow {
        background: #ecf2f6;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
}
.buynow a {
    padding: 10px;

    color: #FFF;
    background-image:url('../img/btn-bg.png');
    border: 1px solid #5c9439;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#pricing_plan1 ul, #pricing_plan2 ul, #pricing_plan3 ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
     border: 1px solid #d9dee1;
}
```

Also if somebody sees things here that could be improved, I would love to hear it. If there are something I can shorten down, or write better for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `padding-left: 0` to your `ul` style declaration.

```
#pricing_plan1 ul, #pricing_plan2 ul, #pricing_plan3 ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    border: 1px solid #d9dee1;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

`<ul>` has default left padding, and that's the reason of your code output.

Check [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R456T/). Both lists have `list-style` set to `none`, but only the second one has additional `left-padding: 0`. As you can see, the first one has exactly the same problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: This worked! For a rookie like me this is great to know / learn. Thank you Marcin!

Answer (score 0):

```
ul
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```